# Non-repudiation is duplicated?

Tags: security, terminology

When we talk about security we have the following requirements:

- authentication
- integrity
- Non-repudiation

Isn't the third requirement included in the first two? If we know *A* sent the message (authentication) and it has not been changed since *A* sent it (integrity) then how can *A* repudiate sending it?

Please don't talk about dig-sig as it's in the technical level. I'm talking about the business requirements.

Comment: isn't it CIA? C for confidentiality

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither authentication nor integrity protections prevent replay attacks. A malicious user can capture a signed and encrypted message and post it multiple times. Therefore a party can repudiate having sent the same message multiple times.

Making each message unique using timestamps and/or nonces addresses this and is therefore used for non-repudiation in combination with signing and encryption.

Answer (score 1):

Non-repudiation is different than integrity and authentication because it implies that the sender is accountable for the contents of a message.

There are many systems that use a key for authentication and integrity, but the authenticated content doesn't mean anything. For example, suppose that in order to authenticate you on my system, I send an unpredictable challenge and ask you sign it and send it back. If the signature is valid, I trust that you know some secret and therefore are who you claim to be. I'd require the key you use for signing these challenges to be designated for digital signatures, but not necessarily for non-repudiation.

Now suppose instead of choosing a random challenge, I try to trick you by sending the challenge, "I will pay erickson one million dollars." If your system signs that, do I have a claim to a million dollars? The signed message is authentic and not tampered with, but unless you signed it with a key flagged for non-repudiation (for example, setting this flag in the key usage extension of an X.509 certificate), you can deny that you were aware of its content and reject my claim.

Non-repudiation makes sense for things like a signatures on documents in a business transaction—cases where you are obligating yourself to some action or payment.

Answer (score 1):

With authentication and integrity, what you can achieve is message *authenticity*, ie. the recipient can be confident that the sender ID and message content are genuine.

Non-repudiation, on the other side, ensures that *none* of the involved party can deny having sent or received the message. In the previous scheme:

- While the recipient can prove that the sender has indeed sent the message,
- The sender itself has no proof that the recipient actually received it.

Non-repudiation systems will therefore include some kind of acknowledgment in order to provide these proofs.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the three security requirements are CIA, i.e.

Confidentiallity
Integrity
Authenticity

But concerning non-repudiation, authentication and integrity dont necessarily provide non-repudiation since integrity says some message has not changed when traveling from **point** X to Y.
Authentication can tell you that some message is sent by **anybody** who has knowlegde of some (shared) secret that **should** be only known to a person.

Imaginge a virus stealing private keys from Alice, in that case you can have integrity of message X and authentication that the message is from Alice (although one can argue if this is real authentication) however, some eavesdropped used the stolen private key to send the message.